# Postgis ST_Distance query returning inaccurate results

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-maps, distance

I am using the following query to retrieve records from a postgresql DB

```
@services = Service.select("*, ST_Distance(services.lon_lat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (lat lon)', 4326)) as st_distance").order("st_distance").limit(10)
```

`services.lon_lat` is a geography type.

After implementing a "get directions" aspect to my app I have noticed a inaccuracy in the distances returned from the above query and the directions in google maps.

It's important to note I did expect a slight discrepancy taking into account the roads to the destination may not be a straight line but it seems the inaccuracy is the other way, for example the 1st returned item in this query says its **216km** away where google maps says **181km**, the 10th says **247km** compared to google maps **203km**...the further the distance the larger the inaccuracy...the 46th item returned if I choose to return that many says **424km** compared to **298km**.

Comment: You probably want to look at [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html). If that doesn't resolve your issue (you have quite big discrepancies, after all), perhaps you could post some actual points.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, as I understood it ST_Distance_Spheroid is for a geometry type, I have a geography type. Is this the case?

Comment: Ultimately, geography is just geometry with a SRID of 4326. All the distance functions work with geometry, but the point of ST_Distance_Spheroid is it returns distance in meters and you specify the spheroid, which will give you very accurate results. ST_Distance works on projected, not geographical coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps you should cast ST_GeomFromText into geography as well?

Comment: this is a good point @user30184, have you experience doing so?

Comment: You can also use the ST_Distance(geography, geography, use_spheroid) version of the function which should give the answer as ST_Distance_Spheroid and will return distance in meters for geography types.

Comment: This is surely another duplicate of the *many* questions about ST_Distance and the appropriate SRID.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have egg on my face with this one...although this was my first thought I ruled it out like an idiot due to passing in my parameters backwards...Thanks everybody

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669045/postgis-st-distance-query-returning-inaccurate-results